# List of Chinese characters not used in Mandarin/putonghua

Tags: characters, topolect, resources

Is there any convenient list of all of these characters?

Examples of such characters being:

The Hokkien (Min)  (which is the pronoun 'them/they/theirs')

The Cantonese/Hakka/Gan [佢](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A2) (which is the pronoun 'he/him/his').

The Cantonese particle [尐](http://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%90) or [啲](http://zh.wiktionary.org/zh/%E5%95%B2) (apparently there is some debate on what the correct character for this should be), which is frequently rendered simply (and rather bizarrely) as 'D'.

Comment: Are you looking only for the characters used in Chinese dialects other than Standard Mandarin or also for those found in Japanese, Korean, Vietnamese which are native only to them? I doubt that such lists exist, but try searching for 方言字, this is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I suppose ideally what I was looking for was a nicely organized complete list. But you are right, probably no such list exists.

Comment: I think this is not a 100% character dictionary, but take a look: http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%8F%BE%E4%BB%A3%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E5%A4%A7%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8

Comment: It's thought that there have been around 50,000 unique characters coined since the beginning of time, of which around maybe 6,000 are used in putonghua. It would be faster to create a list of characters used in putonghua than to create a list of characters not used in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only online dictionary database I can find is 《新华字典》. It is a Microsoft Access database containing 20823 characters. You can run a query on the database and search for "方言" in the "xiangjie"(详解) column. There are shortcomings however, 20823 characters may not be comprehensive enough, and it usually doesn't tell you which dialect the character is used in.

You can download the dictionary database file [here](http://db.myds.cn/download/xhzd.zip).

For Cantonese, there is a convenient list circulating around called [粤语字打法大全](http://www.cantonese.asia/attachments/school/canchars.htm). Wikibooks also has a [character list](http://zh.wikibooks.org/zh/%E7%B2%B5%E8%AA%9E/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97/%E7%B2%B5%E8%AA%9E%E5%AD%97) but there is no definition of meanings. You can find more if you search 粤语字 online.

Comment: Not quite *the* answer, but probably as close as it gets, even the resources available today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Cantodict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/masterlist.htm?action=cantonese) has a list of 265 spoken Cantonese charachters...some are used in Standard Chinese, but with completely different meanings when used in dialect. As for the other dialects...I too am at a loss for resources.